# Login form and dashboard with segments in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, authentication, routes, dashboard, segment

I am pretty new to AngularJS and although I understand basic concepts (I also have years of experience in JS) this is a bit of problem to me.

I want a login form that opens a dashboard with multiple sections accessed from a lateral menu (or breadcrumb element)
For the login part I used some code from [Angular Registration Login Example](https://github.com/cornflourblue/angular-registration-login-example)
but now I want to open the dashboard and enable the route segments (using http://angular-route-segment.com/) for the dashboard navigation menu. How would I go around this?

Can I do this in the dashboard's controller, create another module, or how should I separate login from dashboard?
Would I do it globally, in `app.config` for all routes and segments?

Maybe you know some examples I could use as reference. I guess this is something that you find in many applications

Comment: suggest you use angular-ui-router which supports nested states and a lot of other features far beyond ngRoute. Also heavily used so will get good support with issues here

Comment: A common approach is use a parent state resolve to block non logged in users to all child states where auth required